# How to customize the back button on ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have been able to customize the action bar's background, logo image and text color using suggestions from these:
[Android: How to change the ActionBar "Home" Icon to be something other than the app icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351479/android-how-to-change-the-actionbar-home-icon-to-be-something-other-than-the)
[ActionBar text color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861661/actionbar-text-color)
[ActionBar background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861870/actionbar-background-image)

The last piece I want to customize is the back button image. It's grey by default and I would like it to be white. Either changing the color, specifying a drawable or simply making it transparent (and adding the chevron to my customized logo image) would work. How do I go about that?

Comment: There is no BACK button on the action bar. The BACK button is on the system bar, or is not on the screen (for devices with an off-screen BACK button).

Comment: @CommonsWare, I am not sure what the 'left chevron' in the action bar is called - but that's one I am referring to as the back button. I think it is expected to replace the physical back button on android devices going forward.

Comment: No and no. That is the "up" indicator (despite the arrow orientation). You enable it via `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled()` on `ActionBar`. It is specifically **NOT** supposed to simply go "back". It means that tapping the app icon will go "up" a hierarchy rather than back to the previous activity (as does the BACK button on the system bar).

Comment: @CommonsWare, so what about the new devices that do not have a physical back button, do they all display a 'soft' back button. I have seen a couple of tablets do that. In that case, can I customize the up button to be white instead of the default grey?

Comment: "so what about the new devices that do not have a physical back button, do they all display a 'soft' back button" -- they all should have a BACK button in the system bar.

Comment: just want to add in a lot of cases the UP button *WILL* simply go back. See "When the previously viewed screen is also the hierarchical parent of the current screen, pressing the Back key will have the same result as pressing an Up button -- this is a common occurrence. " from http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html

Comment: @Dori this is true only if there is just one activity after the "root" one. when there are more on the stack, it should usually go to the root. same goes to fragments in case you use them instead.

Answer (score 395, accepted):

The "up" affordance indicator is provided by a drawable specified in the `homeAsUpIndicator` attribute of the theme. To override it with your own custom version it would be something like this:

```
<style name="Theme.MyFancyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/my_fancy_up_indicator</item>
</style>
```

If you are supporting pre-3.0 with your application be sure you put this version of the custom theme in `values-v11` or similar.

Comment: works for me too. I was declaring inside the style set as my ActionBarStyle as in AOSP on github but it was not working - moving out into the main theme did the trick! +1

Comment: `<item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/my_fancy_up_indicator</item>` didn't work for me, but `<item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/my_fancy_up_indicator</item>` did. Guess it's android version thing

Comment: Is there any way to set the top and bottom padding for this to 0dp?

Comment: @JamesMcCracken the only way I was able to do this was via a custom layout.

Comment: @MichałK actually i think that just like all the other stuff you can customize, if you want to handle both API11 and above and below, you need to have both items used.

Comment: use this in main theme， not in actionbarStyle， as [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13168843/actionbarsherlock-changing-homeasupindicator-doesnt-work/13168883#13168883](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13168843/actionbarsherlock-changing-homeasupindicator-doesnt-work/13168883#13168883) works for sherlock 4.4.0

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Showing error. I tried <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_action_arrow_back</item> in the values>styles.xml and values-v11>styles.xml. I am using v7-appcompat library.

Comment: @MSI it seems you're missing something "android:homeAsUpIndicator" not "homeAsUpIndicator" alone

Comment: @ajdeguzman : I applied both. 'android:homeAsUpIndicator' in values-v14, 'homeAsUpIndicator' in default values. It works only for few devices of version sdk 14 and above(works for 4.4 and 4.1 but not for 4.3). For old devices running on 2.3, it doesn't work at all.

Comment: @MSI nope, it says there, v-11 folder

Comment: @ajdeguzman yeah did that too. Anyways, I was actually trying to change the color of up icon. don't work for all devices. Nevermind.

Comment: Is there a possibility to provide padding for the "up" indicator and the logo that I would be using beside it?

Comment: Might be worth noting that if you want the already available holo icons, use @drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_holo_light or @drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_holo_dark

Comment: you are genius @jake and helped me a lot in android learning.

Comment: I had to add it to both the main theme and actionbar theme. Otherwise it did't appear in all activities.

Comment: Anyone made this work with `Navigation Drawer`? I guess `ActionBarDrawerToggle` replaces the up indicator with one of its own, therefore setting it on style has no effect...

Comment: kindly update according to new appcompat support library

Comment: This gave me both the default back arrow and the selected icon instead of replacing the back arrow.

Comment: This is the best way to do it. Because using R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha to change color has risks, as support version changes the drawable resource frequently.

Comment: Note that if your activity doesn't have a parent declared on the manifest, it won't show the icon.

Comment: @JakeWharton This solution seems to not work with Jetpack navigation architecture component. See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54234481/is-it-possible-to-change-up-button-icon-in-navigation-component and this https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/121078028. Despite navigation component reaching version `2.2.1` customizing nav icon is still not supported.

Answer (score 94):

So you can change it programmatically easily by using homeAsUpIndicator() function that added in android API level 18 and upper.

`ActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_yourindicator);`

If you use support library

`getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_yourindicator);`

Comment: If you are using a drawer, you must call `drawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);` before changing the indicator

Comment: @Floss Thank you, setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false / true); solved my problem to set home button as consistent 'Back' and (Open Drawer / Close Drawer) based on my requirements.

Comment: @Floss drawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false); it works for me :)

Answer (score 30):

I have checked the question. Here is the steps that I follow. The source code is hosted on GitHub:
https://github.com/jiahaoliuliu/sherlockActionBarLab

**Override the actual style for the pre-v11 devices.**

Copy and paste the follow code in the file styles.xml of the default values folder.

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_home_up</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Note that the parent could be changed to any Sherlock theme.

**Override the actual style for the v11+ devices.**

On the same folder where the folder values is, create a new folder called values-v11. Android will automatically look for the content of this folder for devices with API or above.

Create a new file called styles.xml and paste the follow code into the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_home_up</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Note tha the name of the style must be the same as the file in the default values folder and instead of the item homeAsUpIndicator, it is called android:homeAsUpIndicator.

The item issue is because for devices with API 11 or above, Sherlock Action Bar use the default Action Bar which comes with Android, which the key name is android:homeAsUpIndicator. But for the devices with API 10 or lower, Sherlock Action Bar uses its own ActionBar, which the home as up indicator is called simple "homeAsUpIndicator".

**Use the new theme in the manifest**

Replace the theme for the application/activity in the AndroidManifest file:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/MyCustomTheme" >
```

Comment: And you can try @drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_holo_light or @drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_holo_dark if you're looking for already available holo icons.

Answer (score 25):

Changing back navigation icon differs for ActionBar and Toolbar.

For ActionBar override `homeAsUpIndicator` attribute:

```
<style name="CustomThemeActionBar" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_nav_back</item>
</style>
```

For Toolbar override `navigationIcon` attribute:

```
<style name="CustomThemeToolbar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="navigationIcon">@drawable/ic_nav_back</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 19):

I did the below code `onCreate()` and worked with me

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_yourindicator);
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Toolbar, you don't need those solutions. You only have to change the theme of the toolbar

```
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"

app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
```

If you are using a dark.actionBar your back button is going to be white else if you are using light actionbar theme it is going to be black.

Comment: Your code works for me, but can we change the color of that indicator?

Comment: colorControlNormal and android:textColorSecondary values are responsible for that but i'm not very sure what else these values also changes. You can try yourself by defining these values on your toolbars theme.

Comment: I'm using "app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"" to display navigationIcon in background white, but it's displaying the default gray icon, i need to change it to blue. "colorControlNormal and android:textColorSecondary" doesn't work.

Comment: Use a custom theme which has "ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" as a parent. This might work.

Comment: Yeah, but what attributes should i use for <item> in custom style?

Comment: I found the solution to change the nav icon, using name="colorControlNormal" not name="android:colorControlNormal". But i want to change to the other drawable, maybe?

Answer (score 2):

tray this:

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_close);
```

inside `onCreate()`;

Comment: It's working but how to get back earlier back button

Answer (score 0):

I used back.png image in the project menifest.xml file. it is fine working in project.

```
<activity
        android:name=".YourActivity"
         android:icon="@drawable/back"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue of Action-bar Home button icon direction,because of miss managing of Icon in Gradle Resource directory icon

like in Arabic Gradle resource directory you put icon in x-hdpi and in English Gradle resource same icon name you put in different density folder like xx-hdpi ,so that in APK there will be two same icon names in different directories,so your device will pick density dependent icon may be RTL or LTR