# How to display custom view in ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I want to display custom search in actionbar (I'm using ActionBarSherlock for that).

I got that:

[image]

But I want make custom layout (edittext field) to occupy the entire available width.

I've implemented custom layout as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750013/actionbar-logo-centered-and-action-items-on-sides).

There is my custom layout `search.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="?attr/actionButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:focusable="true" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/search_query"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_search_edit_text"
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
            android:inputType="text" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_search_arrow" />

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And in `MyActivity`:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_search);

LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.search, null);

actionBar.setCustomView(v);
```

How can I make custom layout to occupy all the available width of `actionBar`?

Help, please.

Comment: Are you able to set the title with custom view set?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

There is a trick for this. All you have to do is to use `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout` as the main container. It's important to have `android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"` set for it. That should do it.

Comment: @Tomik Could you please take a look at my scenario? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516306/sherlockactionbar-missing-title-when-customview-is-set I have missing title after the custom view is set.

Answer (score 37):

I struggled with this myself, and tried Tomik's answer.
However, this didn't made the layout to full available width on start, only when you add something to the view.

You'll need to set the `LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT` when adding the view:

```
//I'm using actionbarsherlock, but it's the same.
LayoutParams layout = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(overlay, layout);
```

This way it completely fills the available space. (You may need to use Tomik's solution too).

Comment: +1, actually, it only worked for me after adding the LayoutParams, thnx

Comment: what is the overlay value?

Comment: @androider is your custom view. Either inflated from xml or created in code.

Comment: And is the idea that you have your toolbar layout and also a customized view? Because that's worked for me even though I assumed the later would override the former

Answer (score 11):

This is how it worked for me (from above answers it was showing both default title and my custom view also).

```
ActionBar.LayoutParams layout = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
// actionBar.setCustomView(view); //last view item must set to android:layout_alignParentRight="true" if few views are there 
actionBar.setCustomView(view, layout); // layout param width=fill/match parent
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);//must other wise its not showing custom view.
```

What I noticed is that both `setCustomView(view)` and `setCustomView(view,params)` the view width=match/fill parent. [setDisplayShowCustomEnabled (boolean showCustom)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(boolean))

Comment: Changing MATCH_PARENT to WRAP_CONTENT as the value of second parameter did the trick. Using LinearLayout...

Answer (score 6):

The answers from Tomik and Peterdk work when you want your custom view to occupy *the entire* action bar, even hiding the native title.

But if you want your custom view to live side-by-side with the title (and fill all remaining space after the title is displayed), then may I refer you to the excellent answer from user Android-Developer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16517395/614880

His code at bottom worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 3):

For example, you can define a layout file which contains a EditText element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/searchfield"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:inputType="textFilter" >

</EditText>
```

you can do

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    // add the custom view to the action bar
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_view);
    EditText search = (EditText) actionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.searchfield);
    search.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

      @Override
      public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
          KeyEvent event) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Search triggered",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;
      }
    });
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM
        | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an example in the launcher app of Android (that I've made a library out of it, here), inside the class that handles wallpapers-picking ("WallpaperPickerActivity") .

The example shows that you need to set a customized theme for this to work. Sadly, this worked for me only using the normal framework, and not the one of the support library.

Here're the themes:

**styles.xml**

```
 <style name="Theme.WallpaperPicker" parent="Theme.WallpaperCropper">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowShowWallpaper">true</item>
  </style>

  <style name="Theme.WallpaperCropper" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/WallpaperCropperActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
  </style>

  <style name="WallpaperCropperActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:displayOptions">showCustom</item>
    <item name="android:background">#88000000</item>
  </style>
```

**value-v19/styles.xml**

```
 <style name="Theme.WallpaperCropper" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/WallpaperCropperActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
  </style>

  <style name="Theme" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
  </style>
```

EDIT: there is a better way to do it, which works on the support library too. Just add this line of code instead of what I've written above:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```