# Android - searchview with auto complete feature inside action bar

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, autocompletetextview, searchview

I want to build an app that has sherlock action bar and a search view inside it. However, i want this searchview to have autocomplete feature like what autocompleteTextView has. Is there any straight forward implementation to do that using searchview alone? or should i use autocompleteTextView inside action bar to do this? I found several posts out there, but none of them are helping me. Those posts talk only about creating a autocompleteTextView , but i want search view to have this functionality. Any idea how can it be done?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For this I have Create one Layout with `AutoCompleteTextView` and add it in `ActionBar` its call `Custom layout in ActionBar.`

After that I have Create Adapter with `android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line`. set it in `AutoCompleteTextView`.

check Below Code:

[image]

```
package com.example.testapp;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;

@TargetApi(11)
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] { "Belgium",
            "France", "France_", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain" };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        // actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        // actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_search);

        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.actionbar, null);

        actionBar.setCustomView(v);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
        AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        textView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
```

Your Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Action Bar:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:inputType="textAutoComplete|textAutoCorrect"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >

        <requestFocus />
    </AutoCompleteTextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

For More Details check this articals: [one](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html), [two](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html) and [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883732/how-to-display-custom-view-in-actionbar)

**Best Luck!**

Comment: Dude, Please add some explanation

Answer (score 1):

I have a simple way to do this without using an autocomplete textview, just put a simple list adapter which contain a ArrayList(itemArrayList) of items, to suggest with search view.Set the adapter to your SearchAutoComplete and auto complete feature will work below is my code.With this, you don't have to use an extra Layout.

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
SearchView mSearchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

SearchAutoComplete searchAutoComplete = (SearchAutoComplete)     mSearchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
searchAutoComplete.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, itemArrayList);
searchAutoComplete.setAdapter(adapter);

SearchManager searchManager =
(SearchManager) getSystemService(this.SEARCH_SERVICE);
mSearchView.setSearchableInfo(
searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
return true;
}
```

Clicking the suggested item the item should appear on the search view so add the below code just after you set your adapter to searchAutoComplete inside the onCreateOptionmenu(...) method.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
long id) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

String searchString=(String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
searchAutoComplete.setText(""+searchString);
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "you clicked "+searchString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
});
```

You can also see the complete code in this [Link](http://androidoze.com/2015/11/12/android-autocompletesearch-view-with-action-bar/)