# AuotCompleteTextView with list of all places in google map in android

Tags: android, google-places-api, android-maps

i know there is lot of stuff on Google map and completed almost all things like showing current location, finding nearest places using Google Place API, searching a place but i want when somebody types in Edit Text for searching places it should show drop down list of all places names matching his entered sub string.
i tried a lot but not found good solution. thanks

Sorry Friends i just got the answer of this question from this link https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete

Comment: for auto complate check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15826444/1168654 and for place i think you have list of places which you want to show or you can also check google map api for places..

Comment: Places Autocomplete Api is answer of this. and thanks Dhaval

Answer (score 0):

You can use google web services API to search to get list of suggested words.
This will provide more information than expected. But you can have a try.

For more on google web service API visit https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete