# Search in actionbar with results appearing in a list above a Map

Tags: android

My app currently opens a new activity when the user clicks the Search button, but I'm having some problems because of a confusion dealing with each activity and fragment lifecycle.

How can I place an edittext in the actionbar that when it gets focused, a list is display above the map like an autocomplete results list?

It's like the Google Maps android app.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom layout for your ActionBar and include an AutoCompleteTextView in this layout. See the accepted answer to this question: [Android - searchview with auto complete feature inside action bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15805397/android-searchview-with-auto-complete-feature-inside-action-bar)

Comment: How can I display the results as Google Maps does? It displays a panel covering the map and display the results in a listview.