# ActionBar custom layout like ICS edit contact

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I just started playing with the new support library with ActionBar support.  I'm trying to implement a bar that looks basically identical to the Ice Cream Sandwich layout on the edit contact screen.  I understand I probably need to implement a custom view something similar to this - [How to display custom view in ActionBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883732/how-to-display-custom-view-in-actionbar).  What I don't understand is exactly what that view is, and the best way to implement it.

Here's the screenshot of what I want in my actionbar:

[image]

Is that just a view with an image and some text, or a styled button, or something totally different?  It has some state pressed properties.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a custom view, by adding the following code when you want the button to appear :

```
// Inflate the view from XML file
LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.search, null);

// Tell the view to occupy the whole actionBar view (MATCH_PARENT)
LayoutParams layout = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
getActionBar().setCustomView(v, layout);
```