# Android copy/paste menu immediately closes

Tags: android, layout, clipboard, copy-paste

How can I make the copy/paste clipboard menu overlay my activity layout rather than squishing it down? This is a problem because once the layout is pushed down the user's finger is no longer touching the EditText view, so the clipboard menu immediately closes, making it impossible to copy from the field. Pretty frustrating.

These screenshots show what I mean - notice that in the image on the right, the tab icons are pushed down compared to the right. I want the clipboard menu to be on top of the tabs.

[image] [image]

With the keyboard, setting [android:windowSoftInputMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) to adjustPan makes it overlay the layout. Anything similar for the clipboard menu? Or any hacks?

Answer (score 2):

The issue was that I hadn't defined my navigation tabs as a custom action bar and had instead just hidden the action bar. The copy/paste clipboard menu takes over the action bar, but if you disable the action bar then it will push the layout down.

The solution was to put my navigation tabs into a custom layout, and then set that layout as a custom action bar:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_activity, null);
ViewGroup actionBarView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_activity_action_bar, null);

final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarView);
actionBar.show();
```

See: [How to display custom view in ActionBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883732/how-to-display-custom-view-in-actionbar)