# Tabs Coming above Action bar when inflating custom layout

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I tried everything mentioned here on all Stackoverflow's other answers but its not working out. Here is my code.

```
actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ffffff")));
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_layout);
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
actionBar.setLogo(null);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
View homeIcon = findViewById(android.R.id.home);
((View) homeIcon.getParent()).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: you mean you want to use your custom layout for action bar ?

Comment: I bet you tried this (http://stackoverflow.com/a/12884297/2438460) too ?

Comment: yes I am using relative layout only

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The tabs show on top when you hide the Home item. It is a bit counter intuitive but it also makes some design sense. They're essentially nudging you to use the tabs as titles for the sections and use the action bar below them for actions inside those sections.

You need `setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME)` to bring the tabs down again. It will probably need a non-null logo too (you can make a 1px transparent one in -nodpi to make it disappear)

Comment: I've tried a number of solutions, this is the first one that works!

Comment: I've one problem .. I can't hide the app icon which displays beside my custom view of my actionBar

Comment: you can also just use a stransparent color as icon:  
<item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="icon">@android:color/transparent</item>

Comment: @Delyan there is a transparent free space at the left of action bar after doing what you have mentioned above. I am using a custom icon using xml so this creates an extra space from left which i don't want. Any idea how to completely remove that space ?

Comment: Btw, there is a [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=36191) for this.

Answer (score 4):

Using the accepted solution leaves a left padding on the `actionbar`, which shrinks your custom view.

the solution is to add this code in the `onCreate` of the `Activity`:

```
        View homeIcon = findViewById(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ? android.R.id.home : R.id.abs__home);
        ((View) homeIcon.getParent()).setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 0));
        ((View) homeIcon).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME); 
        getActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_layout);
```

This worked for me.

Comment: i'd rather use the android:displayOptions in the styles

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use `LayoutInflater` to inflate the view then set the view to the actionbar.

```
    LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.layout, null);
    actionBar.setCustomView(v);
```

And from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12884297/2438460)

> use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout as the main container. It's
>   important to have android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" set for it.
>   That should do it.