# Custom ActionBar Height and ActionBar Tab Height

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar, android-tabs

I want my `ActionBar` and `Tabs` to look like this.

*Please ignore colors*

[image]

Currently it looks like this

[image]

Due to my theme, I have to set the custom `ActionBar` in java.

```
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.custom_action_bar);
```

Here is my `styles.xml`

```
<resources>

    <!-- You are NOT seeing this theme -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar"></style>

    <!-- You ARE seeing this theme -->
    <style name="ScoreBoardStyles" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/CustomTabs</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarSize">160dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:height">80dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomTabs" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator</item>
        <item name="android:height">80dp</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

1. Why is my `ActionBar` below the `TabView`?
2. Why is my `TabView` not changing height?

I am aware there are other questions similar to this, but none of them are this specific.

Any ideas help!

Thank you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it has to do with your custom view. To add tabs all you have to do is actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

Comment: @ksarmalkar the tabs load in fine and function fine. The styling just doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=36191) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19240646/tabs-coming-above-action-bar-when-inflating-custom-layout) might help you. Or do a search, there are more options.