# android actionbar is below tabs in xlarge screens

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-actionbar

In my application, in one of the activities I have 2 tabs displaying different content, the problem is that when I load it in my normal screen device & large screen device it's just fine, tabs are below the actionbar, but when I load it in xlarge screen device, the tabs are moved to the top of the actionbar, here's how I handle my actionbar:

```
    ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
    ab.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    ab.setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar);
    ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    ab.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

I also used :

```
    ab.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

but the result was the same in xlarge screen devices. any idea why is this happening and how to fix it??

**PS:** I know ActionBar is deprecated in android 5.0 and replacing the actionbar is not an option for me at the moment. Later I'll have to replace it but at the moment I have to fix this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try in below order declare ActionBar , its works for me i hope its works for you

```
 actionBar = getActionBar();
 actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
 actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
 actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false); 

 View homeIcon = findViewById(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ?  android.R.id.home : R.id.abs__home);
    ((View) homeIcon.getParent()).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ((View) homeIcon).setVisibility(View.GONE);

 actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

 actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar);
 actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Thanks man I'll check it later, sadly I have to wait until Monday, but thanks anyway.

Comment: It fixed the problem totally and now it's working as I wanted to, I'm gonna accept this as an answer. thanks man... alooott. but please elaborate about that abs_home and what I should put there...

Answer (score 1):

The tabs show on top when you hide the Home item. This is [known issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=36191), but Google marked it as "Working as intended". You can find some ways to fix this in this [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=36191).
Also, please take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19240646/tabs-coming-above-action-bar-when-inflating-custom-layout).