# How to make an action bar, up and down?

Tags: android

How do I make an actionbar up and down? I know that I can use android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"  to make the actionbar get down, but I also want one item to be up. I've searched alot but haven't got any good answers.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use a custom view in the ActionBar and handle its interaction yourself. The split actionbar always puts standard menu entries at the bottom when split.

Comment: ...where the top part of the action bar is used for your icon, title, and any navigation (e.g., drop-down list navigation).

Comment: Can you give me an example on how you could do that, show me in code, I´m new to android. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883732/how-to-display-custom-view-in-actionbar