# how to provide buttons in action bar in android?

Tags: android

I want to provide a `image button` in place of `action bar` and on clicking that I want to display list of options and again on clicking any particular option I want to pass Intent.

How can I achieve this?Does anybody know
If so help me out.

Thank you...

Comment: did your mean about button in action bar is menu option? did you try `android:showAsAction="always"` for `menuItem`?

Comment: I want to provide list of options on clicking on the action bar(say im using overflow icon)If i click on that I want to provide list of options on the top left corner on my screen..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In order to display the imagebutton in Actionbar. First add an item in main.xml.Which is Under MENU Folder.
for ex:
main.xml
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/stopwatch"
        android:orderInCategory="50"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_alarms"
         android:showAsAction="always|withText"
        android:title="Stopwatch"/>

</menu>

then add the following code in your mainActivity.java

@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(item.getItemId())
        {
        case (R.id.stopwatch):
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Stopwatch", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Stopwatch.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

and Don't forget to create another java class as Stopwatch.java

Answer (score 0):

Go through the following link it will help you

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html

Answer (score 0):

You can set a custom view on your action bar, here is the link

[How to display custom view in ActionBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883732/how-to-display-custom-view-in-actionbar)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in two ways
Options 1:  Create an layout XML with your image button, and set that layout to action bar.
For example: In you activity copy the following lines.

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.search, null);

actionBar.setCustomView(v);
```

Now display a `PopUp menu` when the user clicks a `ImageButton`.

Option 2:
      Instead of setting the `view` for the `ActionBar` , you can use sub-`Menu's` in the action bar. For this you need to create sub-Menu.

for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/file"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_new_game"
          android:title="@string/file" >
        <!-- "file" submenu -->
        <menu>
            <item android:id="@+id/create_new"
                  android:title="@string/create_new" />
            <item android:id="@+id/open"
                  android:title="@string/open" />
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>

 Set an icon for the main `MenuItem` so it looks like an `ImageButton`, when the user click the first MenuItem it displays the its sub-`Menu`
```