# Hiding application name

Tags: android, eclipse, android-actionbar

I am developing an application and I want to add some items in the action bar, but I have no place left so I'm wondering if I can remove the application name and replace it with an item? if yes how could I do it?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this thread out: [How to display custom view in ActionBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883732/how-to-display-custom-view-in-actionbar)

It describes how to set a custom view to the ActionBar,
AFAIK it replaces the name of the application.
Try setting a layout with minimum space.

Comment: Is this solution available if I am using a support library(appcompat)?

Comment: Yes. it is. the answer it self is using the compat.

Comment: actually, it was using ActionBarSherlock ! i did some changing and it worked ,I still have some bugs( i will add another question for that ) , so thank you very much for your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set

```
android:label=""
```

for each activity at your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: that did it, but it didn't allow me to use the space left