# Placing linearLayout between ActionBar and Tabs -- Android

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

I was trying to place Linearlayout that contains buttons between The ActionBar and The Tabs, I tried implement a custom actionbar that contains both The ActionBar and a horizontal Linearlayout for the buttons, but I still can't see the buttons, is there any way to do so ?

Here my custom actionBar:  custom_action_bar_with_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="130dp"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:background="@color/blue_buzzvibe">
    <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="60dp"
         android:background="@color/blue_buzzvibe"
         android:orientation="horizontal"
         >

         <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/icon_menu_white"
             android:id="@+id/cab_main_messages_menu"
             android:background="@drawable/top_header_butt"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_weight="0.2"/>

         <TextView 
             android:id="@+id/cab_main_messages_campaign_name"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:scaleType="centerInside"
             android:text="Campaign Of the day"
             android:textColor="@color/white"
             android:textSize="18dp"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:layout_weight="1" 
             /> 
         <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/ic_plus_wh"
             android:id="@+id/cab_main_messages_propose_message"
             android:background="@drawable/top_header_butt"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_weight="0.2" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/options_buttons_campaign"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" >
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/home_desc_butt"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_mail_alt"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_header_selector"
            />
        <View
            android:layout_width="2dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@color/light_gray"
            />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/msg_list_butt_details"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_mail_alt"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_header_selector"
            />
        <View
            android:layout_width="2dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@color/light_gray"
            />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/campaign_metrics"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_metrics"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_header_selector"
            android:clickable="true"
            />
        <View
            android:layout_width="2dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@color/light_gray"
        />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/people_list_butt"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/social_myspace"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_header_selector"
            android:clickable="true"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

In onCreate i call this methode to init my actionbar:

```
public void initActionBar(){
    mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    View customView =  
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_action_bar_with_menu,null);
    mActionBar.setCustomView(customView, new  
    ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
    ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));//(int) (90*scale + 0.5f))); 
    mActionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

     /** Set tab navigation mode */
    mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
}
```

I wan't to make my actionbar height change dynamically, to show all my custom actionBar

Comment: you must put code of your work for help you to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

you can create your custom view in `ActionBar` ( which contains buttons) and set this custom view to `ActionBar` in `OnCreate()` method in your activity

Example:

```
public class YourActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private ActionBar actionBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        actionBar= getActionBar();
            actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
            actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.custom_view);
    }
}
```

[How to create custom view for ActionBar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883732/how-to-display-custom-view-in-actionbar)

Comment: Yes i aleady did it, but the problem, is that my custom actionbar height is bigger then the default actionbar height. so the second linearlayout which contains button is not shown. i'm searching of a way to make my actionbar heigh increase automatically or programmatically. 
i will make a copy of my code if that will help you to understand my problem.
Thank you

Comment: custom view which I mean not override layout of `ActionBar`.
I mean set a custom view for space after home icon of application, like  this question -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883732/how-to-display-custom-view-in-actionbar.
just want to put `TextView` into `ActionBar`

Comment: I had use custom view just for put `ImageView` in center of `ActionBar`, I also use Menu view in `ActionBar` to put another `ImageView` refer to Search icon

Comment: Yes i understand what did you mean.. but it's not what i want. Thank you for your help.
i still searching of the solution yet.