# Do actionbar's icons must be squares?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have been looking for a solution to my doubt but I don't find anything sure.

Do actionbar's icons must be squares? I want put an icon in my actionBar like this:
[image]

But the result that I obtain is this:
[image]
Because my app puts a button with rectangular dimensions in a space of squares dimensions.

I have tried the next:

```
<item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/ActionButtonStyle</item>

<style name="ActionButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton">
<item name="android:minWidth">0dip</item>
<item name="android:paddingLeft">0dip</item>
<item name="android:paddingRight">0dip</item>
```

But this does not solved my problem.

Is it possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. You can do all kinds of crazy stuff in the action bar. I advise looking at the [setCustomView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setCustomView(int)) method of the [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html)

Comment: But, how I should make it? I have declared a RelativeLayout with an ImageView  for this rectangular icon, but how I associate this image with the icon in 'onCreateOptionsMenu()'?

Comment: This shows you how to use it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883732/how-to-display-custom-view-in-actionbar

Comment: Then, if I want associate an action at this icon I have make '(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img).onClick(){ ... }' instead of 'onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){ ... } ??

Comment: Please @Donn Felker, answer me!

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily square if you use custom view in your ActionBar. However, standard action bar icons must be 32dp.

Please refer to [official documentation for more details on iconography](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html) for details.