# Why doesn't my custom action bar view "match parent" when using appcompat and Toolbar?

Tags: android, android-appcompat, material-design

I'm setting a custom view in an action bar. It fills the width of the action bar when using the SDK action bar, but not when using the appcompat version. Why doesn't my linear layout fill the width when using appcompat and Toolbar? And what can I do about it?

Here's what it looks like pre-appcompat:

[image]

And here's what it looks like with appcompat. (The red colour shows the extent of my custom view.):

[image]

*Edit:* Here's how it looks using @Seidan's explicit layout params tip. (Showing black text where it should be white):

[image]

Here's my custom layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#800"
    >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_discard"
        style="?attr/actionButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >

        <TextView
            style="?android:actionBarTabTextStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_close_white_24dp"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:text="@string/actionbar_cancel" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_done"
        style="?attr/actionButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            style="?android:actionBarTabTextStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_check_white_24dp"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:text="@string/actionbar_done" />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here's how I'm setting up the action bar:

```
ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
ab.setDisplayOptions(
        ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM,
        ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
ab.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_discard_done);
```

Both appcompat-v7:22.0.0 and the new appcompat-v7:22.1.0 exhibit this problem.

Comment: have you check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/16652485/1880784?.

Comment: Hmm. That works! But now my text is styled wrong. (I'm having to inflate my custom view now rather than just passing the ID. I guess some context or theme isn't set up right.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks @Seidan for your comment. It led me to a solution. The styling problem was due to the inflater using the wrong theme when I gave it my Activity's *this*.

To summarize, instead of this line from my code in the question...

```
ab.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_discard_done);
```

...I have...

```
View v = LayoutInflater
        .from(ab.getThemedContext())
        .inflate(R.layout.actionbar_discard_done, null);
ActionBar.LayoutParams params = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
        ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
        ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
ab.setCustomView(v, params);
```

Which gives me...

[image: correct action bar]

It's a mystery why we have to specify match_parent in the layout and the code, but I can live with it.

Comment: thank you, thank you, thank you. Just spent hours on this problem and then found your question :)

Comment: Quite simple and elegant solution! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In onCreate

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout_custombar = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout_custombar);

Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int x_size = display.getWidth();


LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_customview, null);


getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(mCustomView);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);


Toolbar parent = (Toolbar) mCustomView.getParent();
parent.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0, 0);


parent.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout_custombar).getLayoutParams().width = x_size;
```