# android - two color Action Bar background

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm using `ActionbarSherlock`. I need to create a background style for the Action Bar as image below.

[image: action bar image]

I can create a plain color background style with a 9-patch image, but this seems quite complex to me. please give me a clue to achieve this.

Comment: Have considered tried a framelayout containing 2 layouts. One with your background and one with the actual content with transparent background?

Comment: use style is more complax use this way http://stackoverflow.com/a/16029214/1168654

Comment: @SverkerSbrg this is actionbar, not a regular layout. im not quite sure this is possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create 9-patch graphics for all action bar heights, that is 48 dp (portrait), 40 dp (landscape) and 56 dp (tablet). Provide the graphics at least in xhdpi.

Here is the graphic for phone, portrait (xhdpi). Rename to **ab_bg.9.png**

[image: 9-patch]

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Styled.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Styled.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="Styled.ActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_bg</item>
</style>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. but if i use this 9-patch actionbar will divide from center. but what i want is a more left weighted layout

Comment: No problem, just expand the black part. Try the updated 9-patch.