# Add image on ActionBar and hide icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I need to do 2 things over the ActionBar:

- First would be adding an image on the right hand side of it.
- Second, hide the icon/logo of the ActionBar's title

The result would be like this:

[image]

To achieve the first, I'm following the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21178860/how-to-add-imageview-on-right-hand-side-of-action-bar), but it doesn't situate the image on the right side, it gets near the title. This is the code extracted from that post:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(actionBar.getDisplayOptions()
        | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(actionBar.getThemedContext());
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
ActionBar.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
        ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.RIGHT
                | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
layoutParams.rightMargin = 40;
imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
actionBar.setCustomView(imageView);
```

This is my imageview containing layout:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ablogo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then, to get the second thing, this is, hide the default title icon, I simply use this:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

Doing this, I get to hide the icon, but the Tabs go above the ActionBar, this is, the actionBar gets situated below the Tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first workaround, I created a layout to set as custom actionBar. The layout would be the same as above's, but the way to define it in the MainActivity changes this way:

```
/*Inflate your custom actionBar layout*/
final ViewGroup actionBarLayout = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.actionbar_logo, null);

/*Ads tabs*/
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

/*Set up your ActionBar*/
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarLayout);
```

This way I get to set the icon on the right hand side. But still have to solve an issue with the title.

For the second workaround, I don't hide/dissable the icon that way, I show it, but then I set it invisible. This way the tabs get perfectly situated under the actionBar.

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

View homeIcon = findViewById(android.R.id.home);
    ((View) homeIcon.getParent()).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```