# How to show a spinner and EditText in android?

Tags: android

I want to create a xml file just as image below. How can I show a spinner with the EditText as shown in fig below?[image] where All Category is a spinner and attached  to it is a EditText. How can I acheive this?

Comment: you need to create custom Action Bar...

Comment: @AnilBhatiya any Tutorial for the same?

Comment: http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-android-program-add-custom-view-actionbar/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026818/actionbar-custom-view-with-centered-imageview-action-items-on-sides

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this layout architecture...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="Search" />

</LinearLayout>
```