# How can I add an ImageButton to an Actionbar in Android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to customize my Actionbar. I want to add an ImageButton in Actionbar, which when clicked goes to another activity. My code is as below. I don't know to proceed forward. can anyone suggest me step by step what to do.

```
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.blue));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a custom view to you action bar inside your activity.

See this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/16029214/713778

Answer (score 5):

To add a button to action bar, locate the onCreateOptionsMenu method in the activity with the action bar that you want to add the button to.
Next go to res>menu>main and add the item based on this example:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings" //<-- id of the view
        android:orderInCategory="100" //<-- not important for the moment (importance)
        android:showAsAction="never" //<-- this will always put it in overflow. set always to show as action
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"/> //<-- Icon to display in action bar
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/> //<-- not really important

</menu>
```

next, we will want to listen for item clicks, so add this method to your activity:

```
    @Override
      public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // action with ID action_settings was selected
        case R.id.action_settings:
        // this is where you put your own code to do what you want.
break;
        default:
          break;
        }

        return true;
      }
```

And there ya go!