# How can i put my logo on Center of Android Action Bar?

Tags: android, android-layout

This is my menu-main.xml.

The picture below the code shows where I want to put the logo on my app.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.akam.billettogram.MainActivity">**strong text**
    <item
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title=""
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

[Position that I want to put my logo in.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvCOL.png)

Comment: Don't. Android Apps don't have logos in the center of the action bar, the action bar should be used to give context of the screen the user is on. Example: photo gallery should have the text "Photos" or "Photo Gallery" in the action bar, not a logo.

Comment: ok thanks for helping

Comment: You would have to define a new toolbar item with a textbox inside (with centered gravity), and set the theme of your Activity as NoActionBar. I will put an example in the answers in a sec.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ActionBar - custom view with centered ImageView, Action Items on sides](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026818/actionbar-custom-view-with-centered-imageview-action-items-on-sides)

Answer (score 1):

So, the easiest way for you to do it is creating a new **Empty** Activity in Android Studio, make sure it is *Empty* and not *Blank*!

This template will build all the code needed:

- It will create your **Activity.java**.
- Create the layout with an `AppBarLayout`, **`Toolbar`** and `CoordinatorLayout`.
- It will create the needed *styles* in your **res/values**.
- It will set the Activity with the proper **style** in the Manifest (NoActionBar).

So... you will just have to add your *icon* and maybe a `TextView` inside the automatically created `Toolbar` (in the **layout.xml**) as seen in the *following snippet*:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_off"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Hello world"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

*Below* is an image with the result:

[image]