# How do I add a logo Image in the Android App Bar?

Tags: android, android-layout

I know you can add an icon image to the app bar, however I was wondering if there is a way to put a larger logo image in the app bar on Android. The picture attached has it behind the app bar but I'm trying to get it inside the app bar. Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16029214/2826147

Answer (score 5):

1) Use latest Android Toolbar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

 <!-- Place your ImageView and Image-->
 <!-- mention image size-->
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Example code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/back_menu_ll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_logo"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textColor="@color/title_first_textcolor"
        android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_title_material"
        android:gravity="left"
        />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

2) You can set logo programmatically:

```
Toolbar tool_bar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
setSupportActionBar(tool_bar);
tool_bar.setLogo(R.drawable.image);
```

For more information about Toolbar, check this link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html

Comment: Does this code go in the app_bar_home_page.xml file or some other location? I get an error: Error parsing XML: mismatched tag at this line "</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>"

Comment: Add Appcompat Libary In Gradale File

Answer (score 3):

For the latest API xml should be,

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar  
  android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
  android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
```

Activity should be,

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);

   Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
   toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_call_black_24dp);
   setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

Comment: Tried this and got an error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{edu.csusb.ossmassistant/edu.csusb.ossmassistant.home_page}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already attached

Comment: I got the error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.setLogo(int)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 1):

As your image is large and rectangle you can set it in background of your action bar :

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar(); 
 BitmapDrawable background = new BitmapDrawable (BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.raw.actionbar_background)); 
 actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
```

For this you can create one `activity` say "BaseActivity" and add snippet in `onCreate` method of it and extend that activity in your all activity where you want to show your change
Or you can have your different square logo like app icon and set it to your action bar icon.

```
public BaseActivity extends Activity{
@override
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
/// add snippet 
}
}

yourActivity/yourActivities extends BaseActivity
```

Comment: Where would this code go? The java file for each activity?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add imageview inside the toolbar

Comment: I tried this and it gave me an error saying it had to be a color value starting with #