# How to make action bar in Android like Facebook

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to make action bar like Facebook which have icon on left side and clickable icon. I Searched a lot but not getting how to make it. I want like this

[image]

Can anyone help me. How can I made this??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a LinearLayout and chuck your buttons, or whatever you need, in it. It's trivial.

Comment: bt I want this in action bar menu @DavidJashi

Comment: Use http://actionbarsherlock.com/ then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Sherlock action bar, it can be customized: http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these similar answers, customize them to fit what you're looking for.

http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/action-bar-search-view/

[ActionBar logo centered and Action items on sides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750013/actionbar-logo-centered-and-action-items-on-sides)