# Display Slider Drawer menu To Right Side instead of left

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have to create an app whose option will come from right side instead of left. I choose [Android Slider menu](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/) and made it custom so that its options are now coming from right side.
I change the gravity from start to End and made some changes in my main activity.
The problem is my Menu Button on whose click drawer appear still coming on left side. 
Its in action bar. How can i move that option to right side instead of left.
See the image hope it will help to understand what i'm trying to say.

[image]

Comment: This is the closest help I could find for you.. http://stackoverflow.com/q/17838955/603744