# Action Bar with centered logo

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like an ActionBar where I place an image/logo in the center of the bar, rather than the default left end. I'm using the standard android classes building with level 18, no compatibility classes and no ABS. I've looked at this solution which seems to be the most popular answer:

[ActionBar logo centered and Action items on sides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750013/actionbar-logo-centered-and-action-items-on-sides)

... but it simply doesn't work for me. I'm using various devices including HTC One with 4.2.2, Nexus 7 with 4.2.1. However much I play with the solution, the text or image still appears left aligned, plus the layout file only takes effect for the width of the image, and does not span the entire ActionBar.

My request is just for the solution to centering the logo, I'm not interested in any left or right home/menu buttons.

Comment: then why not just hide the actionbar and create a view with your text where you want

Comment: Note that this violates Android design aesthetics. This was specifically mentioned in [the Common UX Issues episode](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pEGWcMTxs3I) of the Android Design in Action video series.

Comment: Point well and truly taken! That's a great video, thanks for the link, which I shall ensure my clients see!

Comment: However this does leave me with a design issue. The app only has one menu for navigation (with just 4 items) for which I use onCreateOptionsMenu, so that they drop down from the '3 dots' on the top right of the ActionBar. Without the logo, the bar will look very bare, and there's no need for any left button or drawer menu. Is it ok to have a left logo, which has no action assigned to it?

Answer (score 1):

A centered logo on the ActionBar actually violates the Android Application Design Guidelines unfortunately, you can find a comprehensive guide here:

http://developer.android.com/design/get-started/ui-overview.html

The accepted norm is to have the logo to the left hand side.