# How can I center a menu item in an action bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

How can I center a menu item in an action bar? I am using an image icon in action bar as menu but it appears at the right side of the action bar and I want to center it. Is it possible in android ?

Comment: It is possible, however could you provide more information about the context where you are trying to do this, perhaps sharing the xml file would help.

Comment: Are you referring to the overflow (3 dots) icon?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    
    <!-- Search Widget -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
          android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"/>
</menu>

Comment: Is it on the top or bottom actionbar?

Comment: top of the action bar

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using custom views in actionbar. **In native actionbar view you can't set alignment of menu items**. Check here another [**SO post for custom action bar**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750013/actionbar-logo-centered-and-action-items-on-sides?lq=1)