# Center Logo In Action Bar

Tags: android

I'm trying to centre an app logo in the centre of the App.

```
 MainActivity Code:
    public class ProfileActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
        private SlidingTabLayout slidingTabLayout;
        private ViewPager viewPager;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
            centreLogo();
            viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.my_pager);

            viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapterFrag(getSupportFragmentManager()));

            slidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);

            // (R.id.sliding_tabs).setDistributeEvenly(true);
            slidingTabLayout.setViewPager(viewPager);
            // viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            setUpTabColor();
        }

@Override
    public android.support.v7.app.ActionBar getSupportActionBar() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.getSupportActionBar();
    }

    private void centreLogo() {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        if (findViewById(android.R.id.home) != null) {
            findViewById(android.R.id.home).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.activity_profile, null);

        ActionBar.LayoutParams params = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
                ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(view, params);

        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#F3F3F3")));
    }

    private void setUpTabColor() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        slidingTabLayout
                .setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
                    @Override
                    public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return ProfileActivity.this.getResources().getColor(
                                R.color.material_blue_grey_800);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public int getDividerColor(int position) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return ProfileActivity.this.getResources().getColor(
                                R.color.material_deep_teal_200);
                    }
                });
    }
```

The error message I am getting is below:
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The method setCustomView(View, ActionBar.LayoutParams) in the type ActionBar is not applicable for the arguments (View, ActionBar.LayoutParams)

Comment: possible duplicate of [ActionBar logo centered and Action items on sides](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750013/actionbar-logo-centered-and-action-items-on-sides)

Comment: No action items added yet.

Comment: You can use that answer to serve your own needs. You don't need an action item.

Comment: Nope, not a duplicate. I'm nt using ActionBar Sherlock

Comment: Java Null pointer error if I use ActionBar logo and Action items on sides

Comment: Are you mixing support library and regular android.app imports?

Comment: I'm using these import libs: import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;