# Center position of logo in Action Bar Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

I want to display the logo at the centre of the Action Bar. Here's my custom layout code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ActionBarWrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:padding="8dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And in the `onCreate()` I'm using it as:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_logo);
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#2A2A2A")));
```

The issue is it displays fine in normal Fragments and Activity but shifts a little to the right when used with Navigation Drawer. Here are the images:

1. Wrong One:

[image: Wrong Display]

2. Right One:

[image: Right Display]

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750013/actionbar-logo-centered-and-action-items-on-sides

Comment: Not the same problem.

Answer (score 13):

Then try ToolBar. Try this code

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" >


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Toolbar Title"
    android:src="@drawable/logo"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: It works better with "src"
android:src="@drawable/logo"

Answer (score 5):

Try using Linear layout and `layout_gravity` like this :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/ActionBarWrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="8dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

hope it help

Comment: it works for me when I change the orientation to "vertical"

Answer (score 5):

Add `app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"` to your `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`, because a toolbar with menu drawer will automatically have a right margin.

Answer (score 5):

I used a Drawable as background of the Action Bar. In this way you can use different MenuItem on left and/or right and the logo will be everytime centered.
I needed to animate also the logo when it has been loaded through Picasso, and this is the result:

[image: Action bar logo loaded through Picasso with fade animation]

I've used a LayerDrawable for animating just one Drawable (a layer) into it.
This is the code, maybe could be useful for someone:

```
getSupportActionBar().show();
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

showActionBarLogo(this, true);
```

And this is the showActionBarLogo function for showing and hiding the Action bar logo:

```
public void showActionBarLogo(final Activity activity, boolean show) 
{
    if (show) 
    {
        // Calculate Action bar height
        int actionBarHeight = 200;
        TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
        if (activity.getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true))
        {
            actionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data,activity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        }

        // Using action bar background drawable
        logoTarget = new Target() {
            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {

                Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[2];
                layers[0] = new ColorDrawable(Color.RED); // Background color of Action bar
                BitmapDrawable bd = new BitmapDrawable(activity.getResources(), bitmap);
                bd.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                Drawable drawLogo = bd;
                layers[1] = drawLogo; // Bitmap logo of Action bar (loaded from Picasso)
                LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);

                layers[1].setAlpha(0);

                ((AppCompatActivity) activity).getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(layerDrawable);

                ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(layers[1], PropertyValuesHolder.ofInt("alpha", 255));
                animator.setTarget(layers[1]);
                animator.setDuration(2000);
                animator.start();
            }

            @Override public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) { }
            @Override public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) { }
        };

        Picasso.with(activity).load("https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png").resize(0, actionBarHeight).into(logoTarget);

    } else {
        ((AppCompatActivity) activity).getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.RED));
    }
}
```

I've created a drawable for the Action Bar with:

- a layer (0) which is a background color and
- a layer (1) with the
  logo in the middle of it (with fade animation)

I load the logo with Picasso and I like to animate it when has been loaded (bitmap onBitmapLoaded callback).

Bear in mind to declare Picasso Target out of showActionBarLogo function to avoid garbage issue on loading images:

```
private Target logoTarget;
```

If you don't need the Picasso loading, you can use only the code into `onBitmapLoaded` function and using a Drawable instead of the bitmap variable.

Same thing if you don't need the fade animation. You can remove the `layers[1].setAlpha(0);` line and also all the `ObjectAnimator` lines.

I've tested it from Android 4.4 (api 19) to 8.1 (api 27) and it works great!

I hope this could help!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ActionBarWrapper"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="clip_horizontal" // change from center attribute
    android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:src="@drawable/tap1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Using the attribute clip_horizontal did the trick for me.

```
android:layout_gravity="clip_horizontal"
```