# ActionBarSherlock: changing homeAsUpIndicator doesn't work

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-xml

I'm want to change the up icon with applying the following style to my activity, but it doesn't work and but I still get the default black '<' icon.

Can anyone find out what is missing here?

```
<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/actionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/actionBarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="actionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/header_bar</item>
    <item name="background">@drawable/header_bar</item>

    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/up_indicator</item>
    <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/up_indicator</item>
    <item name="android:displayOptions">homeAsUp|showHome</item>
    <item name="displayOptions">homeAsUp|showHome</item>

</style>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If I remember correctly, <s>I worked around this issue by moving</s> you should move the `android:homeAsUpIndicator` and `homeAsUpIndicator` elements into the main theme declaration. In other words, try:

```
<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/actionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/actionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/up_indicator</item>
    <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/up_indicator</item>
</style>

<style name="actionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/header_bar</item>
    <item name="background">@drawable/header_bar</item>
    <item name="android:displayOptions">homeAsUp|showHome</item>
    <item name="displayOptions">homeAsUp|showHome</item>
</style>
```

<s>Not sure whether I also had to move up the `displayOptions`, but you may want to give that a go too in case above doesn't work right away.</s>

By the way, I find naming a style `AppTheme.ActionBar` and then inheriting from `Theme.Sherlock.Light` rather confusing. If it were an ActionBar specific style, I would've expected something like `Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar` (or any of the other widget styles) as the parent. If it's your main theme, I'd name it accordingly. Up to you of course.

---

**Edit:** Updated answer after Jake's comment.

Comment: Moving it into the theme isn't a workaround, it's the appropriate location for this. The `displayOptions` should remain inside the action bar style declaration.

Comment: Thanks. This works great. My only problem is the image i want to use is bigger than the default up image. The system adds padding the same width as the custom up image, even when its not showing... any ideas?

Comment: Thanks it helped and worked i was scratching my head over it from last two days

Comment: @JakeWharton, your comments are lifesaving as ever! Admiring your job