# Not able to change the Up caret next to the app icon in the ActionBar in my Navigation Drawer

Tags: android

I am currently trying to implement the new NavigationDrawer as per the Google IO 2013 guidelines. I am using ActionbarSherlock. The code is working well. The only issue is that I am not able to toggle the "up" caret next to my app icon when the navigation drawer is pulled out. I am pasting my entire code below. Kindly help.

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
   private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
   private ListView mDrawerList;
   private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

   private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
   private CharSequence mTitle;
   private String[] mPlanetTitles;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
      mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
      mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
      mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer);

      mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
      mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
      mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

      mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, /* host Activity */
      mDrawerLayout, /* DrawerLayout object */
      R.drawable.ic_drawer, /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
      R.string.drawer_open, /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
      R.string.drawer_close /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
      ) {
         public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); 
         }

         public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); 
         }
      };

      getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
      getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);


      mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

      if (savedInstanceState == null) {
         selectItem(0);
      }

      new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
             prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
             opened = prefs.getBoolean(OPENED_KEY, false);
             if(opened == false)
             {
                     mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
             }
        }
    }).start();
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
      inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
      return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
      menu.findItem(R.id.action_websearch).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
      return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {
      if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(getMenuItem(item))) { 
         return true; 
      }

      switch (item.getItemId()) {
         case R.id.action_websearch:
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
            intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, getSupportActionBar().getTitle());
            if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
               startActivity(intent);
            } else {
               Toast.makeText(this, R.string.app_not_available, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return true;
         default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
      }
   }

   private android.view.MenuItem getMenuItem(final MenuItem item) {
      return new android.view.MenuItem() {
         @Override
         public int getItemId() {
            return item.getItemId();
         }

         public boolean isEnabled() {
            return true;
         }

         @Override
         public boolean collapseActionView() {
            return false;
         }

         @Override
         public boolean expandActionView() {
            return false;
         }

         @Override
         public ActionProvider getActionProvider() {
            return null;
         }

         @Override
         public View getActionView() {

            return null;
         }

         @Override
         public char getAlphabeticShortcut() {

            return 0;
         }

         @Override
         public int getGroupId() {

            return 0;
         }

         @Override
         public Drawable getIcon() {

            return null;
         }

         @Override
         public Intent getIntent() {

            return null;
         }

         @Override
         public ContextMenuInfo getMenuInfo() {

            return null;
         }

         @Override
         public char getNumericShortcut() {

            return 0;
         }

         @Override
         public int getOrder() {

            return 0;
         }

         @Override
         public SubMenu getSubMenu() {

            return null;
         }

         @Override
         public CharSequence getTitle() {

            return null;
         }

         @Override
         public CharSequence getTitleCondensed() {

            return null;
         }

         @Override
         public boolean hasSubMenu() {

            return false;
         }

         @Override
         public boolean isActionViewExpanded() {

            return false;
         }

         @Override
         public boolean isCheckable() {

            return false;
         }

         @Override
         public boolean isChecked() {

            return false;
         }

         @Override
         public boolean isVisible() {

            return false;
         }

         @Override
         public android.view.MenuItem setActionProvider(ActionProvider actionProvider) {

            return null;
         }

         @Override
         public android.view.MenuItem setActionView(View view) {

            return null;
         }

         @Override
         public android.view.MenuItem setActionView(int resId) {

            return null;
         }

         @Override
         public android.view.MenuItem setAlphabeticShortcut(char alphaChar) {

            return null;
         }

         @Override
         public android.view.MenuItem setCheckable(boolean checkable) {

            return null;
         }

         @Override
         public android.view.MenuItem setChecked(boolean checked) {

            return null;
         }

         @Override
         public android.view.MenuItem setEnabled(boolean enabled) {

            return null;
         }

         @Override
         public android.view.MenuItem setIcon(Drawable icon) {

            return null;
         }

         @Override
         public android.view.MenuItem setIcon(int iconRes) {

            return null;
         }

         @Override
         public android.view.MenuItem setIntent(Intent intent) {

            return null;
         }

         @Override
         public android.view.MenuItem setNumericShortcut(char numericChar) {

            return null;
         }

         @Override
         public android.view.MenuItem setOnActionExpandListener(OnActionExpandListener listener) {

            return null;
         }

         @Override
         public android.view.MenuItem setOnMenuItemClickListener(OnMenuItemClickListener menuItemClickListener) {

            return null;
         }

         @Override
         public android.view.MenuItem setShortcut(char numericChar, char alphaChar) {

            return null;
         }

         @Override
         public void setShowAsAction(int actionEnum) {


         }

         @Override
         public android.view.MenuItem setShowAsActionFlags(int actionEnum) {

            return null;
         }

         @Override
         public android.view.MenuItem setTitle(CharSequence title) {

            return null;
         }

         @Override
         public android.view.MenuItem setTitle(int title) {

            return null;
         }

         @Override
         public android.view.MenuItem setTitleCondensed(CharSequence title) {

            return null;
         }

         @Override
         public android.view.MenuItem setVisible(boolean visible) {

            return null;
         }
      };
   }

   /* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
   private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         selectItem(position);
      }
   }

   private void selectItem(int position) {
      // update the main content by replacing fragments
      Fragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
      Bundle args = new Bundle();
      args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
      fragment.setArguments(args);

      FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
      fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

      // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
      mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
      setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
      mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
   }

   @Override
   public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
      mTitle = title;
      getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
   }

   /**
    * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
    * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
    */

   @Override
   protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
      // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
      mDrawerToggle.syncState();
   }

   @Override
   public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
      super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
      // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
      mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
   }

   /**
    * Fragment that appears in the "content_frame", shows a planet
    */
   public static class PlanetFragment extends SherlockFragment {
      public static final String ARG_PLANET_NUMBER = "planet_number";

      public PlanetFragment() {
         // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
      }

      @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_planet, container, false);
         int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PLANET_NUMBER);
         String planet = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array)[i];

      // change int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier(planet.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()), "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
         int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier("tempmap", "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
         // change ((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageResource(imageId);
         ((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageResource(imageId);
         // change  getActivity().setTitle(planet);
         getActivity().setTitle("MapView");
         return rootView;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

If you don't need the 3 lines to move (like in gmail app), you could just add:

```
<item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_drawer</item>
<item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_drawer</item>
```

in your activity's theme. I prefer this to using yet another library in my app.

ic_drawer can be downloaded from here:
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: Just to reiterate, this goes in the main theme declaration and not any custom ActionBar style declaration you may have. Ref: [ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13168843/actionbarsherlock-changing-homeasupindicator-doesnt-work]

Comment: The trick here is the mirrored attributes, as required in ActionBarSherlock: http://actionbarsherlock.com/theming.html.

Answer (score 11):

try to call syncState on the toggle drawer like this:

```
    @Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

//your ActionBarDrawerToggle is below
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
```

or just right after you instantiate it.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and did some research on that topic. It does not seem to be easy to get the caret working correctly on older SDKs. Long story short, there's a guy who has a running example implementation that's based on reflection:

https://github.com/nicolasjafelle/SherlockNavigationDrawer

I tested it and it works perfectly for me, even on Android 2.x !

Answer (score 0):

I have the caret removed in 4.x devices, but not for 2.x devices.  The repository is here if you need it:
https://github.com/bcrider/NavigationDrawerSherlocked

It's simply the sample that Google supplied that I modified using ActionBarSherlock as you have done as well.  I fixed an issue with a method (onOptionsItemSelected) in the sample that originally prevented the tapped icon from doing anything after ActionBarSherlock was integrated into the app.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Brian. But I could not make out what changes you have made in onOptionsItemSelected method that can fix the issue I am facing. Kindly explain. I also replaced my onOptionsItemSelected method with yours. But that did not fix the issue for me either. Thanks

Comment: Oh sorry, this fixed an issue where tapping the up carat and icon would no longer work when ActionBarSherlock was integrated into the code.  I had hoped this would at least fix your issue on 4.x devices but 2.x still has it.  Not the worst as it's more or less a standard, but I can see where it would be nice to have it removed.