# Android, How to replace up/back caret in the ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

Minimum SDK version that I'm supporting is 14. I have Action bar in my application and everything about it's functionality is okay.

My only problem is up or back caret which is gray color. I want to have it white color. Therefore, I designed similar caret with white color in different sizes.
so my question is how to replace gray/default caret with mine?

So what I did? Based on what [this guy said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17341422/513413), I added 
`<item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_drawer_back</item>`
 into my app theme like this:

```
<style name="Theme.Example" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        ...
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Example</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.Solid.Example" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
        ...
        <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_drawer_back</item>
    </style>
```

Although I'm telling `ic_drawer_back` image should be loaded as caret but when I run the app default(gray) caret is still displaying.

Did you face this problem before? any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks

```
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ){
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();

                // display view for selected nav drawer item
                displayView(selectedDrawerItem);
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
//        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
//        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Luckily I found where my problem was. I mistakenly had put

```
<item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_drawer_back</item>
```

in `ActionBar.Solid.Example` instead of `Theme.Example`.
So it's working fine now.