# How to change image of homeAsUpIndicator in default theme Theme.Holo.Light

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-image

In my android application,

I am using default theme Theme.Holo.Light.

Now I want to change the "<" sign which is default using this :

```
 <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@android:drawable/ic_ab_back_holo_light</item>
```

By changing this into

```
 <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
```

But here sign remains as it is,It doesn't change image.I am attaching screen shot of actionBar. Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13168843/actionbarsherlock-changing-homeasupindicator-doesnt-work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put these in your default `Activity`theme.

```
<item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
```

Comment: You mean in themes.xml file ? Because I am using Default theme : Theme.Holo.Light

Comment: Make your custom theme with `Theme.Holo.Light` as its parent.
`<style name="my_custom_theme" parent="Theme.Holo.Light">
<item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
</style>`

Comment: So I make custom theme like this :  <style name="customTheme" parent="Theme.Holo.Light"> <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_launcher</item> </style> in style.xml file ? Thanks.

Comment: Yes,It works but Image size is so big ..It covers lot of space in actionBar.How can I decrease image size ?

Comment: put image in `drawable-xhdpi` folder and remove it from its previous folder.

Comment: That works perfect..Now I want to remove logo of theme.because it looks like this : http://postimg.org/image/ha7je9y3x/ .If I remove logo from manifest file then it displays default android photo.How can i remove this logo ? Thanks.

Comment: `Actionbar ab = getActionBar();
ab.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);`

Comment: I am using this : ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
  actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);So when I add line end of this then it does not change. actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);

Comment: If its working that's fine or use this `getSupportActionBar().setIcon(android.R.color.transparent);`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36154/discussion-between-ponting-and-mihir)

Comment: putting image in drawable-xhdpi does reduce size of image, but but it still covers wide width. How can i eliminate this?

Comment: i've put it in the main theme inside theme.xml and is not working!