# Android appcompat API 10 collapse action view

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat, android-search

I'm currently developing and Android app that needs to support Api10+
I followed many tutorials to set appcompat to manage to create the action bar.

links like: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21291156/2789106
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

There are only three things that I cannot do.

1. When the search opens, the search magnifier does NOT change to the drawable I set.
2. I cannot change the "back" icon (the home up button, left to the logo (it's a diferrent image than the one I passed in the creation of the `drawerToggle`))
3. I cannot programmatically close (collapse) the action view when the keyboard Search is clicked. (calling `collapseActionView()` was inplemented in API 14)

Here's my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
    // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_navigation_drawer,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_close) {

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

    };

    // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    // Restore app state if any
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        mLeftMenuContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.left_menu_container);
        mLeftMenuContainer.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                // return TRUE to avoid tap on back view
                return true;
            }

        });
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mLeftMenuContainer);

    }

    // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_action_bar_logo);

}

/* Called whenever we call supportInvalidateOptionsMenu() */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content
    // view
    if (mDrawerLayout != null && mLeftMenuContainer != null) {
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mLeftMenuContainer);
        for (int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++) {
            menu.getItem(i).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        }
    }

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);  
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    mMenu = menu;
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_bar_search);
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchableInfo info = searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName());

    searchView.setSearchableInfo(info);  

    AutoCompleteTextView searchText = (AutoCompleteTextView) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
    searchText.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_action_bar_search_text));
    searchText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_action_bar_search_text));

    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);

    // Getting the 'search_plate' LinearLayout.
    View searchPlate = searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_plate);
    // Setting background of 'search_plate' to personal defined drawable.
    if (searchPlate != null) {
        searchPlate
            .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.texfield_search_view_theme);
    }

    // Set search view clear icon
    ImageView searchIconClearView = (ImageView) searchView
            .findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_close_btn);
    if (searchIconClearView != null) {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Should Change Clear Icon here");

        searchIconClearView
            .setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_bar_clear_search);

    }

    // Set search view Magnifier icon
    ImageView searchIcon = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_mag_icon);
    if (searchIcon != null) {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Should Change Search Icon here");
        searchIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_bar_back);
    }

    // Set on click to open a fragment, not a activity
    final SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            // Do something
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Performed search with: " + query);
            searchView.clearFocus();
            return true;
        }
    };

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener);

    MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchItem, new OnActionExpandListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem arg0) {
            mMenu.findItem(R.id.action_bar_cart).setVisible(true);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem arg0) {
            getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_bar_logo);
            mMenu.findItem(R.id.action_bar_cart).setVisible(false);
            return true;
        }


    });

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Can someone please tell me if I'm doing something wrong?

-- EDIT --

I managed to fix question number 1 and 2:

What you need to do is to define the homeUpIcon in your Theme. So If you are supporting API 10 like me:

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="searchViewSearchIcon">@drawable/your_search_icon</item>

    <!-- API 13- Support -->
    <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/your_back_icon</item> 

    <!-- API 14+  -->
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/your_back_icon</item> 

</style>
```

found in
[ActionBarSherlock: changing homeAsUpIndicator doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13168843/actionbarsherlock-changing-homeasupindicator-doesnt-work)
and
[Changing the background drawable of the searchview widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085308/changing-the-background-drawable-of-the-searchview-widget/11669808#11669808)

The most important question is still pending and if anyone knows the answer please post here!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this:

```
   public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        MenuItemCompat.collapseActionView(searchItem);
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I had to have the MenuItem setup with `app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|always"` before this would work.