# How to change home as up resource programmatically?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I know how to [change the homeAsUpIndicator in the styles xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9265774/435605). **The question is how to change it programmatically**.

The reason I want to do it because in some views I support **side navigation** (sliding menu) - pressing the up/back title button, shows the side menu.

In other views I support the **natural up/back** botton.

Thus I would like to different indicator icons to indicate the two different logics - side navigation vs. up/back.

Please, lets not argue on the motivation of doing this. That's the given state. Thanks.

Comment: Although resource (upId) is found, and new ImageView defined, at Galaxy S3 device this hack not works. However, when i tested at Nexus 4, works fine.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
int upId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("up", "id", "android");
if (upId > 0) {
    ImageView up = (ImageView) findViewById(upId);
    up.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_drawer_indicator);
}
```

Comment: Works, but feels like a hack. Is this documented? Can the `up` name change in the future?

Comment: I would say it is a hack. However, it is the only way to get to the view. It could be changed in the future but I can't imagine a reason for this to happen.

Comment: As seufagner said, I validated that this does **not** work on the Samasung Galaxy S3.

Comment: Samsung got their firmwares tweaked from android. it actually refers to android.R.id

Comment: i check it. it does not working on android 4.1.1 and older (od 4.2.2+ works fine)

Comment: It works with Nexus 4.4, Samsung 4.1 device, but not with Samsung 2.3, Nexus 7 4.3 device!!! Any idea? Any work around way?

Comment: @matthias Its working like charm in higher version. But how we can make this work for lower version as well. ?

Answer (score 16):

The solution by @matthias doesn't work on all devices, A better solution to change the `homeAsUpIndicator` is to set it @null in style and change the logo resource programmatically.

Below is my code from style.xml

```
<style name="Theme.HomeScreen" parent="AppBaseTheme">
  <item name="displayOptions">showHome|useLogo</item>
  <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@null</item>
  <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@null</item>
</style>
```

In code you can change the logo using `setLogo()` method.

```
getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_holo_light); //for ActionBarCompat
getActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_holo_light); //for default actionbar for post 3.0 devices
```

Also note that the `Android API 18` has methods to edit the homeAsUpIndicator programatically, [refer documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setHomeAsUpIndicator%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29).

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.my_home_as_up)
```

Comment: Is there a way to add padding left when used `getSupportActionBar()`? Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Although [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16404232/2668136) might achieve the expected behaviour, as you can read in the comments below it: "*This hack does not work on some devices*". I found another way according to [Adneal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23486947/2668136) which gives me the clue and specially the right way to do.

- Lower API: use id **R.id.up** to retrieve the related `ImageView`.
- API >= 14: get the relative `Parent` of Home `ImageView` (**android.R.id.home**) and retrieve the first child which is the `UpIndicator` (**android.R.id.up**).

Then, this snippet code changes dynamically the `UpIndicator`:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
    // get the parent view of home (app icon) imageview
    ViewGroup home = (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.home).getParent();
    // get the first child (up imageview)
    ( (ImageView) home.getChildAt(0) )
        // change the icon according to your needs
        .setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_icon_up));
} else {
    // get the up imageview directly with R.id.up
    ( (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.up) )
        .setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_icon_up));
}
```

I have not tested on multiple devices (that's why I'm not sure this above code works for all devices), however this seems to work great in APIs mentioned in [the update part here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23486202/2668136).

*Note: If you don't make the difference between higher and lower APIs, you will get a NullPointerException because `R.id.up` is not available in higher API while `android.R.id.up` is not available in lower API.*

Answer (score 2):

I write solution for this. It's not beautiful but works:

```
public static ImageView getHomeAndUpIndicator(View decorView) {
    ImageView res = null;

    int upId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("up", "id", "android");
    if (upId > 0) {
        res = (ImageView) decorView.findViewById(upId);
    } else {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 10) {
            ViewGroup acbOverlay = (ViewGroup)((ViewGroup)decorView).getChildAt(0);
            ViewGroup abcFrame = (ViewGroup)acbOverlay.getChildAt(0);
            ViewGroup actionBar = (ViewGroup)abcFrame.getChildAt(0);
            ViewGroup abLL = (ViewGroup)actionBar.getChildAt(0);
            ViewGroup abLL2 = (ViewGroup)abLL.getChildAt(1);
            res = (ImageView)abLL2.getChildAt(0);
        } else if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 10 && android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
            ViewGroup acbOverlay = (ViewGroup)((ViewGroup)decorView).getChildAt(0);
            ViewGroup abcFrame = (ViewGroup)acbOverlay.getChildAt(0);
            ViewGroup actionBar = (ViewGroup)abcFrame.getChildAt(0);
            ViewGroup abLL = (ViewGroup)actionBar.getChildAt(1);
            res = (ImageView)abLL.getChildAt(0);
        } else {
            ViewGroup acbOverlay = (ViewGroup)((ViewGroup)decorView).getChildAt(0);
            ViewGroup abcFrame = (ViewGroup)acbOverlay.getChildAt(1);
            ViewGroup actionBar = (ViewGroup)abcFrame.getChildAt(0);
            ViewGroup abLL = (ViewGroup)actionBar.getChildAt(0);
            ViewGroup abF = (ViewGroup)abLL.getChildAt(0);
            res = (ImageView)abF.getChildAt(0);
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

As a param put: *getWindow().getDecorView()*

Test on few devices (nexus 7 (4.4.2), samsung galaxy s+ (2.3.6), yaiu g3 (4.2.2)) and emulators with  android 2.3.3 and 4.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code

```
final Drawable upArrow = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_black_24dp);
        upArrow.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#000000"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
```