# How to disable the background color when HomeUp is pressed?

Tags: android-actionbar, android, android-homebutton

**Background:**

I currently enable the `HomeUp` button on `Activity`, thanks to:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

According to the [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)), it's related to [`setHomeButtonEnabled`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setHomeButtonEnabled%28boolean%29) which:

> Enables or disables the "home" button in the corner of the action bar [...] Setting the constant *DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP* display option *(setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled method)* will automatically enable the home button.

Also, I customize with a `selector` the state background of items in `ActionBar` with this style:

```
<style name="MainTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/ab_item_background</item>
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/ab_item_background</item>
</style>
```

Although this works well, I don't want to use a drawable `selector` for the `HomeUp` button when `UpIndicator` is enabled.

**Why do I need it:**

The ActionBar's background is grey (relative to `Theme.AppCompat.Light`) and the selector uses a green background when items are pressed. However, the app icon is also green which, when it is pressed, merges with the background pressed state. I need to avoid this by not using a drawable for HomeUp's background.

**Question:**

How can I achieve this, any idea about a workaround?

*Notes:*

1. I tried to search a related `attribute`, which allows to use a custom background for the app icon and UpIndicator, to customize in `style.xml` but I didn't find it in the [Resources](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html).
2. If I use `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` and `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)`, I have the expected behaviour for the Menu Items (backgrounds changed relative to its states) but the HomeUp button, although I have the right behaviour with its background, is no longer enabled.
3. Also, I want to avoid using a `CustomView` to the ActionBar.

---

**Update:**

According to [Adneal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23486947/2668136) and after tests and researches, here is the results:

```
 _______________________________________________________________________________
|     |                        |                         |                      |
| API |       R.id.home        |    android.R.id.home    |        method        |
|_____|________________________|_________________________|______________________|
|     |                        |                         |                      |
|  8  |          OK            |           --            |    getParent() x 1   |
| 10  |          OK            |           --            |    getParent() x 1   |
| 11  |          OK            |           --            |    getParent() x 1   |
| 12  |          OK            |           --            |    getParent() x 1   |
| 13  |          OK            |           --            |    getParent() x 1   |
| 14  |          --            |           OK            |    getParent() x 1   |
| 15  |          --            |           OK            |    getParent() x 1   |
| 16  |          --            |           OK            |    getParent() x 1   |
| 17  |          --            |           OK            |    getParent() x 2   |
| 18  |          --            |           OK            |    getParent() x 2   |
| 19  |          --            |           OK            |    getParent() x 2   |
|_____|________________________|_________________________|______________________|
```

Then, the right condition should be:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
    // retrieve the two parents with "android.R.id.home"
} else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
    // retrieve the first parent with "android.R.id.home"
} else {
    // retrieve the first parent with "R.id.home"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the background of the home button to `null` by using [`View.getParent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getParent%28%29).

[This is the layout that contains the home button](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/action_bar_home.xml#L28), once inflated in [`ActionBarView`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/widget/ActionBarView.java#L198), is added to the [up container layout](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/action_bar_up_container.xml#L20) which is what actually uses the `actionBarItemBackground` attribute.

However, [`AppCompat`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarView.java#L218) doesn't utilize an "up container" layout, as well as the normal `ActionBar` up to API level 18 (Jelly Bean MR2).

So, to change the home button background you'd make one call to `View.getParent` when using the support library or API levels 11-17's `ActionBar`, but two when you're changing API level 18+'s.

```
    View home;
    final int version = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (version >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
        // Normal action bar, post-"up container"
        home = (View) findViewById(android.R.id.home).getParent().getParent();
    } else if (version >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        // Normal action bar, pre-"up container"
        home = (View) findViewById(android.R.id.home).getParent();
    } else {
        // Support library action bar
        home = (View) findViewById(R.id.home).getParent();
    }
    home.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
```

`AppCompat` could be updated in the future to include to an "up container" layout, so bear in mind you may need to adjust your code later on to accommodate for that.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much to share your knowledge and good related links!

Comment: Adneal, I think there is something wrong in your condition: I get some *NullPointerException* in API 3.+ with *android.R.id.home*. That's being said, I changed to *ICE_SCREAM_SANDWICH* and everything seems to worked well.

Comment: @Fllo Oh, you're right. I forgot the "up container" wasn't added to the `ActionBar` until API level 18 (Jelly Bean MR2). I think you meant to type API **13**, in which case I can't really say what the `ActionBar` layout is like because Honeycomb isn't open source, but either way I made an edit. I'm sorry, that's all a little confusing.

Comment: I updated my answer with several tests I made. The right condition is mentioned in this update part. I think you should update your answer too. Anyway, thanks a lot to have given me the clue. It works definitely well on all API tested.

Comment: @Fllo Ha, nice table. You should be careful though about API level 17 though. I dove a little deeper and it looks like the "up container" isn't added until 4.2.2_r1, so there are *some* versions of Jelly Bean that won't work correctly.