# Customizing up Button in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat

I want to customize the `up button`, I am using `appcompat library` for my actionbar. I don't want the default up button which android provides. Because I am using `actionbar` that has produced by [style generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/). So that up button looks pale with the color of `actionbar` that I selected. Can someone please suggest me how to achieve it? I have searched lot but couldn't find.

[image]

I have prepared my own image for it. So I want to replace that with my image. I believe it is possible. Because googleplay displays the actionbar with up button in different color in the apps section.

Below is the styles.xml:

```
     <style name="Theme.Customab" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_customab</item>
        <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Customab</item>
        <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Customab</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Customab</item>
        <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Customab</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Customab</item>
        <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_customab</item>
        <item name="actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_customab</item>
        <item name="actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Customab</item>

                <!-- Light.DarkActionBar specific -->
        <item name="actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Theme.Customab.Widget</item>

**<item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/customup</item>**


    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.Solid.Customab" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="background">@drawable/ab_solid_customab</item>
        <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_customab</item>
        <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_customab</item>
        <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Customab</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.Transparent.Customab" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="background">@drawable/ab_transparent_customab</item>
        <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Customab</item>
    </style>

    <style name="PopupMenu.Customab" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">    
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_customab</item>  
    </style>

    <style name="DropDownListView.Customab" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown">
        <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_customab</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Customab" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_customab</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DropDownNav.Customab" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_customab</item>
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_customab</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_customab</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ProgressBar.Customab" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_horizontal_customab</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionButton.CloseMode.Customab" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.CloseMode">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_cab_done_customab</item>
    </style>

    <!-- this style is only referenced in a Light.DarkActionBar based theme -->
    <style name="Theme.Customab.Widget" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Customab</item>
        <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Customab</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `getActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.drawable_to_use))`?

Answer (score 6):

Adding this item to your custom theme that is related with pre-Honeycomb will give an error because that attribute does not exist in the Android framework on older devices.

```
<item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/action_up_caret</item>
```

Instead of "android:homeAsUpIndicator" you should override "homeAsUpIndicator" attribute in your custom theme if you are using AppCompat library.

```
<item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/action_up_caret</item>
```

Note: Here's the AppCompat source if you're interested. https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/tree/master/v7/appcompat or https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v7/appcompat/

Here is some of the files of the my test project:

values\styles_example.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>

    <style name="Theme.Example" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_example</item>
        <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Example</item>
        <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Example</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Example</item>
        <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Example</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Example</item>
        <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_example</item>
        <item name="actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_example</item>
        <item name="actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Example</item>

                <!-- Light.DarkActionBar specific -->
        <item name="actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Theme.Example.Widget</item>

        <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.Solid.Example" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="background">@drawable/ab_solid_example</item>
        <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_example</item>
        <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_example</item>
        <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Example</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.Transparent.Example" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="background">@drawable/ab_transparent_example</item>
        <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Example</item>
    </style>

    <style name="PopupMenu.Example" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu"> 
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_example</item>   
    </style>

    <style name="DropDownListView.Example" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown">
        <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_example</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Example" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_example</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DropDownNav.Example" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_example</item>
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_example</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_example</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ProgressBar.Example" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_horizontal_example</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionButton.CloseMode.Example" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.CloseMode">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_cab_done_example</item>
    </style>

    <!-- this style is only referenced in a Light.DarkActionBar based theme -->
    <style name="Theme.Example.Widget" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Example</item>
        <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Example</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

values-v14\styles_example.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>

    <style name="Theme.Example" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_example</item>
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Example</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Example</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Example</item>
        <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Example</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Example</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_example</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_example</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Example</item>

                <!-- Light.DarkActionBar specific -->
        <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Theme.Example.Widget</item>

        <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.Solid.Example" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_solid_example</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_example</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_example</item>
        <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Example</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.Transparent.Example" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_transparent_example</item>
        <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Example</item>
    </style>

    <!-- this style is only referenced in a Light.DarkActionBar based theme -->
    <style name="Theme.Example.Widget" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Example</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Example</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

This way should able to able to get a look like [this](http://i.minus.com/ijPiyTH6DSW1U.png) in your activity.

Comment: Added this line in Them.customab style tag, but doesn't show up. Am I missing something or misplacing it?

Comment: I made a small test using the emulator(2.1) to check the answer and it worked perfectly. I also added the item same place in styles xml file. If you used style generator probably you have two style.xml: one in values\styles_yourstylename.xml and one in values-v14\styles_yourstylename.xml. Add "<item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/action_up_caret</item>" to values\styles_yourstylename.xml and add "<item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/action_up_caret</item>" to values-v14\styles_yourstylename.xml. And test it again, this may be your issue.

Comment: +1 and Please see my edit. I have added the same way in both the styles. But I don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't know where the issue is but I edited my answer to add my sample project files that modify up indicator. You can compare the related parts with your files.

Comment: @hcelaloner  how to do this Button for Appcompat lib?  android:Widget.Button to @style/Widget.AppCompat.Button be not working!!

Answer (score 0):

Keep your image in drawable folder 
specify attribute .

```
android:logo
```

Because ActionBar will use the android:logo attribute of your manifest, if one is provided. That lets you use separate drawable resources for the icon (Launcher) and the logo (ActionBar, among other things).

Comment: Sorry this is wrong answer. My question is about up navigation button and your answer is about the icon next to the up button.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used `AppCompat`, but it's pretty simple(but hard to find out) on Android 4.0.

You need to add the following item to your Application theme XML.

```
<item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/action_up_caret</item>
```

Comment: I have seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252354/how-to-customize-the-back-button-on-actionbar but I want to apply it for the app compat styles. whenever I try to add this in styles, it shows as error that no resource is found with this homeAsUpIndicator.

Comment: Can you update your question with your Application style xml?

Comment: @rick Your Theme.Customab should be able to take this value

Comment: Are the rest of the theme properties being applied? And have you set the theme to the Application?