# make android HomeAsUp icon bigger

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

As title says, how do I make the android HomeAsUp icon `<` bigger? I.e. I need to change its size. I know I can do things like

```
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

But how do I resize the mark?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but answer by [Jake](https://stackoverflow.com/users/132047/jake-wharton) on [How to customize the back button on ActionBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252354/how-to-customize-the-back-button-on-actionbar/9265774#9265774) question may help. You can define a customized drawable instead of default HomeAsUp indicator like:

```
<style name="Theme.MyFancyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/my_fancy_up_indicator</item>
</style>
```

You can try to make the drawable of a bigger dimension. It might work. I haven't tried that though.