# hide up button and show icon as home in action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

```
actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

i have this code to hide title and up button in my code and show only the icon but my problem is when i click on the icon it doesnt work anymore meaning it does not bring me to home activity anymore but when i set `actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);` to `true` it works ok any idea on how to make this work the way i want it to work

Comment: [implementing-navigation/ancestral.html](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html)

Comment: @SimplePlan sir i was able to make it run properly with the icon and "<" what im trying to achieve here is to hide the "<" and still make the icon a link to home i was able to hide the "<" in my code but icon does not work or does not link to home i have read your link it is not stated there how to achieve what i want any idea you have is appreciated..thanks

Comment: I don't think so that it's worked, you can do 2 thing, 1- change image of "<" to one empty image (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18816418/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-actionbars-up-arrow) 2- create your layout and put that on top of your layout and hide default `ActionBar`

Comment: i tried your first solution what i did is to put this code on style <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@null</item> unfortunately it didnt work any idea on how to change that image to an empty image?

Comment: have you tried  with other image? if it's worked with other image create one transparent image and set that as image.

Comment: <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/note</item> unfortunately it gives error so maybe we cant change that icon the only way is to remove it permanently but how