# ActionBarSherlok + DrawerLayout in Android 2

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, drawerlayout

I use ActionBarSherlok and DrawerLayout, all works fine, but in Android 2.3 ActionBar drawer icon not displays. Insted it displays back icon. In Android 4 displays drawer icon.

[image]

How can I change back icon in Android 2 to drawer icon like in Android 4?

I use next code to initialize drawer:

```
drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
drawer.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer,
        R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.main_01, R.string.main_02) {
    public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(drawerTitle);
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
};

drawer.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);     
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Check out similar post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252354/how-to-customize-the-back-button-on-actionbar

Answer (score 1):

The "up" affordance indicator is provided by a drawable specified in the `homeAsUpIndicator` attribute of the theme. To override it with your own custom version it would be something like this:

```
<style name="Theme.MyFancyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
   <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/my_fancy_up_indicator</item>
  </style>
```

If you are supporting `pre-3.0` with your application be sure you put this version of the custom theme in `values-v11` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

`ActionBarDrawerToggle` is for the native API Level 11 action bar, and perhaps for the AppCompat action bar (not sure about that one).

For ActionBarSherlock, either use a [Sherlock-aware drawer implementation](https://github.com/tobykurien/SherlockNavigationDrawer), or implement workarounds as described in [this issue](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/941) and [this issue](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/pull/946).