# How to change Home button on action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I disabled icon on Action bar, and enabled  Home button

```
 ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle("Reg");
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

How can I change icon for Home button (arrow back) or delete this arrow icon near title.
Can I change it by Themes or should make new layout?

screen - http://saveimg.ru/show-image.php?id=887d66190718b170a311162d1b08ae0c

Comment: Take a look at the same post here http://stackoverflow.com/a/9265774/1671933

Comment: Glad to help, hope you get it fixed.