# Change up button icon

Tags: android

I'm making a 4.0+ app, using the native actionbar.

How can I change the icon used for the up button (the arrow icon)? Ideally I could do this programatically.

Thanks

Comment: Programmatically, I don't know, but you can certainly do it with a custom theme, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252354/how-to-customize-the-back-button-on-actionbar

Comment: Yeah looks like there's a method for it in ActionBar, but only from api 18 onwards sadly.

Answer (score 0):

for example:

```
Button btn = new Button(this);
btn.setText("New Todo");
btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.new_todo_image);
```

or an existing object

```
btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.image);
btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.new_todo_image);
```

The Actionbar logo

```
final android.app.ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
bar.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
```

Comment: Oh I meant specifically the up button on the actionbar.

Comment: Please attach print Screen think about which button