# Change the color of the icon that opens the navigation bar, located in the toolbar

Tags: android, menu, themes, nav

I am trying to change only the color of the icon that opens the navigation drawer. I have tried using a few solutions found on here like IconTint and the one current in my themes.xml file. The tint only changed the color of the icons in the drawer, not the toggle itself. Thanks!

```
Main Layout
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="@color/light_black"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/white"    />
    
        <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="211dp"
            tools:openDrawer="start">
    
    
            <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    
                app:headerLayout="@layout/header_layout"
                app:menu="@menu/menu_layout"
                android:id="@+id/nav_view"/>
        </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
    
    
    </LinearLayout>


Themes

    <resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
        <!-- Base application theme. -->
        <style name="Theme.WeNote" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
            <!-- Primary brand color. -->
            <item name="colorPrimary">#673AB7</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
            <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/teal_700</item>
    
    
            <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
            <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
            <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
            <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/white</item>
            <!-- Status bar color. -->
            <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">@color/black</item>
    
            <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    
            <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
            <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
            <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle</item>
        </style>
    
        <style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
            <item name="color">@color/white</item>
        </style>
    
    </resources>
```

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24482825/changing-navigation-drawer-icon-on-action-bar-android

Comment: mDrawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(drawable)