# How to change color of ic_drawer in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I want to change the color of ic_drawer to white. Yes the three lines icon that you can see below.

Could you point me to any solution via xml?

Currently, I have the white icons ready.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible by just setting a color code, you have to do it with custom images.For generating a navigation drawer indicator icon, use the [Android Asset Studio.](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-nav-drawer-indicator.html)
Insert the images in your res/drawable-XXXX folder (replace XXXX with hdpi, mdpi, etc.), under a name like **custom_ic_drawer**.
If you followed [the tutorial on the Android Developer portal](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) for creating a navigation drawer, you created a drawer toggle with the following code:

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close)...
```

Replace this line with the following:

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.custom_ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close)...
```

This way the toggle will have your custom icon.
If you want to change the icon for the Up navigation (the grey caret on your left picture, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252354/how-to-customize-the-back-button-on-actionbar).