# How to change the up navigation icon in android on searchview expand

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-search

i'm using actionbarsherlock for my actionbar. I have a sliding menu and searchview. when the application get launches, it will automatically pick the up navigation icon from style.xml file.

When the search menu gets expanded, the up navigation icon will not get changed, it will be still looking like 3 line slider menu. How to change the up navigation icon when searchview is expanded?. I have represented the flow in below image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- [Create custom back button theme](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9265774/1008278) with parent of your custom theme.

`<style name="MyThemeForSearch" parent="@style/MyCustomTheme">
        <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/my_back_indicator_for_search</item>
    </style>`

- Set theme in runtime when Search is expanded., i.e `onClick` 
  [`setTheme(R.style.MyThemeForSearch);`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.html#setTheme%28int%29)

Comment: Ya, that works well when i launch the app, there i have placed 3 strips bar image. Now, when my search expanded, how to update there to arrow?

Comment: Could you please provide me snip of code, setTheme is supported in API 8?

Comment: setTheme is available from API-1

Comment: i tried like this, `@Override
    public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {     
     mAddnewtaskmenu.setVisible(false);
     setTheme(R.style.arrowtheme);`} it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

check your layout drawable's whether you have set an image like 3 liner slide menu 
when you create navigation drawer it automatically sets default image  which will be loaded representing  3 liner slide like you mentioned change your ic_drawer.png image and replace image with what icon you wish.
also you might go check changing your theme

```
> <style name="Theme.MyFancyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
>     <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/my_fancy_up_indicator</item>
> </style>
```