# How to change colour of home up button in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, textcolor, programmatically-created

I have used this code to show homeupbutton in action bar.

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Now I want this back button to be blue or any other colour that I want. How can I do this programmatically.?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252354/how-to-customize-the-back-button-on-actionbar

Comment: You link does not provide the solution to di it programmatically as needed here.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is, to change programmatically the up carret color :

```
    int upId = getResources().getIdentifier("up", "id", "android");

    if(upId > 0)
    {
        ImageView up = (ImageView) findViewById(upId);
        up.getDrawable().setColorFilter (Color.CYAN, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    }
```

If you are using ABS, add this :

```
    if (upId == 0) {
        upId = R.id.abs__up;
    }
```

You might need to do something similar if you use ActionBarCompat.

This code will also change the three lines icon if you are using the navigation drawer !

Comment: where should I add this code?

Comment: I tried it with OnResume (because I have different colors for each activity).