# How to change Up button Android ActionBar?

Tags: java, android, xml

I searched many solutions and implemented solution of [Jake Wharton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252354/how-to-customize-the-back-button-on-actionbar)

My style.xml code is

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/aeromyorders</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_actionbar</item>
        <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/up_caret</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

but still my Actionbar up button is default what i have to do now? i also replaced Vaues-v11 style also.. My Min SDK is 15 Max 19 in Manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code in Your Activity. set Your Custom Back Button

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_actionbar_screen_back);
```

Hope it helps...