# Setting HomeAsUpEnabled(true) but hide back button actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I can't seem to find a solution for this anywhere.  I just want to make the logo clickable in my activity, but it seems the only way to do this is setHomeAsUpEnabled(true), but this makes the back icon visible and clickable. I want to make the logo clickable, why isn't this possible?  Do I have to create a custom view for this?

Comment: try making the back button transparent. See here for more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252354/how-to-customize-the-back-button-on-actionbar

Comment: try use `setHomeAsUpIndicator` to change.

Comment: is it toolbar, look for the logo and handle it,,

Comment: Looking at the appcompat Toolbar source you'll notice that there is an ImageView called mLogoView. It's unfortunately private so I can't set an onclicklistener on it. Set the back button to transparent doesn't work either. I would need to set the back button to the logo. This is quite a hacky solution.