# How to change the default up button icon in ANDROID API 22

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design, android-actionbar-compat

I want to change the default **home up button** Icon of Action Bar in **API Level 22**

I am using **AppCompatV7** for **API Level 22** and I am extending **ActionBar Activity**.

Currently it looks like

[image: default]

and want to change it as

[image: Required]

What we have done:

In my default theme style I wrote following code

```
<item name="android:actionModeCloseDrawable">@drawable/up_button</item>
```

but it does not seems to work.

Comment: By the way: `ActionBarActivity` is deprecated. Use `AppCompatActivity` instead.

Answer (score 4):

**I have done like this. it may help others.!!**

```
mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);//set false default

toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.menu_icon);//add custom home buton

     toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.START);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I have to do it through XML. I am not using toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the attribute of the up button in the theme is called `homeAsUpIndicator`:

```
<item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/up_button</item>
```

More info and posible solutions [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252354/how-to-customize-the-back-button-on-actionbar)

Hope it helps