# Show circle over back button on action bar

Tags: android, button, android-actionbar, customization

I have a custom action bar. I create action bar layout with `button` and `TextView`. I want, when user press back button, change view of back button. like gmail app that user click on back button, a rectangle shows over back button but I want shows circle over back button. I want to link images but I have not allow.

I don't know how can calculate radius of circle for any size of devices. 
Thanks for advises and sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Please give me any Screen Shot so i get any idea for that also

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. http://tinypic.com/r/25aoily/8 this url shows my mean

Comment: this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252354/how-to-customize-the-back-button-on-actionbar

Comment: I think, you can't understand my mean.  I can to change layout of back button but I want to create circle over button. i think this is a new button and set with selector but i don't know how can find circle's radius. Thanks :)

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/implementing-material-design-in-your.html... this will help you to get that effect

Comment: Hi TestAndroid May be you need like of this:https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect

Comment: @Jackson Chengalai thanks for your link. This is good document for designing application :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to do two different icons one with circle around and another one without it. Then you won't have any problem with the sizes of devices.

You can do it with a selector like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/your_icon_with_circle"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/your_icon_without_circle" />
</selector>
```

And then you can set the selector into the button background