# Aligning items in support actionbar appcompat

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-appcompat, android-actionbar-compat

I have an `appCompatActivity` with a `supportActionBar` similar to `whatsApp chat screen` interface. Having been able to customise the `actionbar` with all the necessary components, I am not not able to apply padding/margin of any sort on the leftmost `up/back` button. However, with rest of the items I set up in the `toolbar` are aligned properly.

Here is how my `layout` of the activity looks like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/relMainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/avatar"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/action_bar_avatar_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/action_bar_avatar_size"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtUserName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

...
```

In the activity:

```
mImageViewAvatar = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.avatar);
        mTextViewUserName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtUserName);
        final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    mImageViewAvatar.setBackgroundImage(Contacts.getImage());
        mTextViewUserName.setText(recipientId);
```

I have tried to set my `layout_marginLeft` to a negative value as well to the image even, it does not move to left. How do I apply margin/padding alignments to only this `toolbar`? Not the toolbar used in the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you're looking for `app:contentInsetLeft` respectively `app:contentInsetStart`. Setting these attributes to `0dp` will remove the padding - see the following two screenshots:

Without explicity setting contentInset:

[image: picture - without setting inset]

Setting contentInset to 0dp

[image: picture - inset set to 0dp]

**Please note:** This won't work if you're using `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` since the drawable which will be used by the system has a padding which can't be removed. See the following Screenshot:

[image]

So if you're trying to achieve the same as WhatsApp you have to use your own "back-button" drawable and add it to your `Toolbar` layout.

#### Edit

That's how I would do it:

***.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_back_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_arrow_back" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/avatar" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:text="StackOverflow"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**Java code**

```
    Toolbar tb = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(tb);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);
    View view = findViewById(R.id.layout_back_button);
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });
```

**Result:**

[image: result picture]

Notice that I wrapped the back button drawable and the avatar in an extra layout, which has the `selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` set as the background. Due that we achieve this ripple effect like in WhatsApp.

Comment: So if I manage to replace the `homeasupindicator` with my own drawable in the `style.xml` following this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252354/how-to-customize-the-back-button-on-actionbar), and then apply the above configuration, will it work?

Comment: I don't think so. The system seems to block always the same amout of space for the navigation icon, no matter how the icon looks like (I just tested it). So ultimately this means you have to put it in your *.xml file and handle the clicks on the icon by yourself. As an info: Setting `android:homeAsUpIndicator` won't work for the `Toolbar`, you have to set it at runtime via `mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.myIcon);`.

Comment: Can you please show me in an example, where and how exactly in my `.xml` file should I place this icon? Also if you have suggestion if I use `actionbarsherlock` instead? And its compatibility with `appcompat`?

Comment: @faizanjehangir See my edit. Result is almost the same as seen in WhatsApp.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much.